# Rufus Freedos doesnt work

Tags: rufus, freedos

Yo guys im trying to create a FreeDOS USB from Rufus. But when i do it it seems to not creating the full FreeDOS OS. No config.sys can be found and none of the DOS commands work except ''dir''. I have no idea what is wrong can somone pls help me?

Comment: Do you use FullUSB from here: http://www.freedos.org/download/ ?

Comment: I have tried it and it works, the problem is tho, it formats the drive to FAT when i do it in rufus with that FreeDOS in your link. And when it formats it to FAT instead of FAT32 i have no space to add other files to the drive. Rufus says it formats it to FAT32, but after the format it says that the drive is just FAT. ANy idea why this happens?

Comment: Returning to MS DOS 3.x FAT was the default filesystem. Why this happen now I have no idea, but you should check how to add driver for FAT32 (if it's required).

Comment: Alright ill look into that.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

> when i do it it seems to not creating the full FreeDOS OS

Of course it doesn't. When using the *FreeDOS* option from the Boot selection dropdown Rufus creates a **BARE MINIMUM** FreeDOS bootable drive, that will boot to a command prompt and that's it. It is up to you to add the executables for any additional commands you need.

The full FreeDOS OS is more than 100 MB, so, obviously, a 1 MB application will not magically add 100 MB of DOS commands to a USB drive. Instead it expects you to extract these commands from the FreeDOS ISO (since you already have a bare minimum FreeDOS bootable drive, so you can just drop what you need).

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, I GOT IT TO WORK NOW AND I HAVE ENOUGH SPACE. THANK YOU SO MUCH BEEN STUCK AT THIS FOR SO LONG, UR THE BEST <333333